# Counterexample - Increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

My intuition says that the statement is false. Anyone out there know of counterexamples?

> Suppose $f: R\to R$ and $c\in R$ such that $f'(c) > 0$.  So, $\exists \varepsilon> 0 $ such that $f\mid_{(c-\varepsilon, c+\varepsilon)}$ is increasing.

([Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBOEi.png))

Comment: In fact, it is "increasing". I fixed it. tks!

Comment: I vote against closing this question.

Comment: If the derivative is continuous in $c$ then the conclusion is true.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/539773/462) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/634387/462) for additional information.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo very useful, many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $$f(x)=\cases{ x+2x^2\sin(1/x), & $x\ne0$\cr 0, &$x=0$}.$$ $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(0)=1$. But $f$ is not monotonic in any neighborhood of $x=0$ (since in any neighborhood of $0$, $f'$ takes both positive and negative values).

This is [Example 3.5](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA37&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)
 in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis*.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your attention! Do you have an easier example?

Comment: @user125303 I don't think there is an easier example. The concept is simple, though: take $y=x$ and add a differentiable "infinite oscillatory" part to it.

Comment: Or, being naive (and possibly wrong) about things, take $g(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne0$; $g(0)=0$ (which has derivative $0$ at $x=0$) and tilt it's graph.

Comment: Now I got your point. Thank you!! The comments from the others were also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x):=\begin{cases}x,&\text{if $x\in\boldsymbol {Q}$}\\
\tan(x),&\text{if $x\in\boldsymbol{R}\setminus\boldsymbol{Q}$}\end{cases}$, for $c=0$ we have $f'(c)=1$.  Here we have a punctal monotony: there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $x_1\in ]-\epsilon,0[$ and $x_2\in ]0,\epsilon[$ we have $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, but $f$ is not increasing on $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[$ for any $\epsilon>0$: chose an irrational $a\in]0,\epsilon[$ and a rational $b\in]0,\epsilon[$ with $a<b$, then $f(a)>f(b)$.