# Proving DifferentiabilityRigorously

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Assume that real function $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with $f'(x_0)>0$.  How would one show that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $$ f(x)>f(x_0) $$ for all $x$ in between $x_0$ and $ x_0 + \delta $.

Is it always true that $f$ is increasing on an interval $(x_0, x_0+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: For the second part, take $f(x)=x+2x^2\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$. $f'(0)=0$ but $f'$ takes both positive and negative values in every nhood of $0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra His assumption is that $f'(x_0) > 0$, when in your example $f'(0)=0$

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Oops. I meant $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Present a function with specific feature](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539741/present-a-function-with-specific-feature)

Answer (score 3):

Since $f'(x_0) > 0$, you know that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h} > 0
$$
Hence (why?), $\exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$
0 < h < \delta \Rightarrow f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) > 0
$$
Hence
$$
f(x) > f(x_0) \quad\forall x\in (x_0, x_0+\delta)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** write the definition of differentiability as
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+ (x-x_0)\epsilon(x-x_0)
$$with $\lim_0\epsilon = 0$ and write an $\epsilon-\delta$ thing with the function $\epsilon$.

details:

when $(x-x_0)$ is small enough and positive, $|\epsilon(x-x_0)| < f'(x_0)/2$ because $f'(x_0)>0$.
For such an $x$ we have
$$
f(x) - f(x_0) = (f'(x_0)+\epsilon(x-x_0))(x-x_0) > (f'(x_0)-f'(x_0)/2)(x-x_0)
= f'(x_0)(x-x_0)/2>0
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find $\delta$ such that if $|x - x_0| < \delta$, then $\frac12 f'(x_0) < \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} < \frac32 f'(x_0)$.