# Function continuous a.e. and Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Weierstrass theorem says that any continuous function on a compact interval is bounded. Is this also true for functions continuous except countably many points (ex. monotone functions)? If not, how monotone functions (so continuous except countably many points) on compact intervals are always Riemann integrable?

Comment: This is not true for every a.e. continuous function; but its *is* true for monotonic functions (and very easy to check directly).

Comment: Sorry, I mean continuous fucntions with countably many discontinuities. not a.e.

Comment: This is not true either for functions with countably many discontinuities; even for functions with just one discontinuity point.

Comment: But it is true for monotone functions (even with countably many discontinuities, yes)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Because if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is monotonic, then $\vert f(x)\vert$ is always between $\vert f(a)\vert$ and $\vert f(b)\vert$.

Comment: ohh, im so stupid

Comment: @Etienne I know what you mean, but it's not true as written, e.g. $f(x)=x$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Thursday You're right, of course. "Between" is definitely not the correct word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every monotone function on $[a,b]$ is bounded, because $f(x)$ is always between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$; hence $|f(x)|\le \max(|f(a)|,|f(b)|)$.

Boundedness is not enough for Riemann integrability, but monotonicity helps again: the same in-betweenness idea applies on subintervals, as in [this answer by Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/920868/).

Without monotonicity, even one discontinuity point can make a function nonintegrable, like $f(x)=1/x^2$ on $[-1,1]$.