# Example of a continuous function that is monotone at no point

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen examples and proofs of functions that are everywhere continuous but nowhere monotone. However I have never seen a proof and example of a function that is everywhere continuous but monotonic at no point. Do you know of an example (preferably with a proof) or can you provide an accessible reference?

P.S Definition of monotonic at a point:
Let $x$ be a real number. We say that $f$ is non-decreasing at $x$ if there is a neighborhood of $x$, $N_x$, such that $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \ge 0$ if $y \in N_x-\{x\}$. We say that $f$ is monotone at $x$ if $f$ is non-decreasing at $x$ or non-increasing at $x$.

Comment: have you seen this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42326/nowhere-monotonic-continuous-function

Comment: @JC574 Yes, thanks. But that is about monotonicity in an **interval**.

Comment: It seems Andres Caicedo's answer there contains what you're looking for.

Comment: yes I should have said, look at Andres answer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I managed to get hold of the book mentioned on that answer and it has a lot of interesting stuff!

Answer (score 0):

The **Weierstraß function** is indeed continuous everywhere but monotone nowhere.

See also: [Nowhere monotonic continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42326/nowhere-monotonic-continuous-function)

Comment: but is it monotonic at no **point**?

Comment: @Student: The Wierstrass nowhere differentiable function has, at each point, a Dini derivate equal to $+\infty$ and a Dini derivate equal to $-\infty,$ which implies that at each point the function is not monotone. Indeed, this implies the stronger result that at each point the function is not of monotonic type. The function $f$ is not of monotonic type at $x=a$ means that for each real number $m,$ the function $f(x) + mx$ is not monotone at $x=a.$ See [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-01/S0002-9939-99-04571-2/S0002-9939-99-04571-2.pdf) for more details.