# Is every function that can be integrated using Riemann integral must be monotonic function?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

Is every function that can be integrated using Riemann integral must be monotonic function?

If false then is there an example.

Comment: Do you know any examples of Riemann integrable functions? Are they all monotonic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. $\sin(x)$ is Riemann integrable between $0$ and $\pi$. In fact, any non-monotone continuous function on a compact set.

An example of a *nowhere* monotone continuous function is given [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42326/nowhere-monotonic-continuous-function). (A function is **nowhere monotone** if there is no nonempty open set on which it is monotone.)

Comment: Great, Thanks for help.