# Is it possible to prove that for any non-constant continous real function there is an interval on which the function is strictly monotonous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I came across this question when I tried to solve a math problem, and my solution was heavily based on this statement above.
I find it very intuitive because you can't draw a continous function from one point of the plane to another (with different y's) without having to draw the line such that it is possible to find a very small interval on which the function is strictly increasing/decreasing.
My question is the following: is this statement provable (and how the proof would unfold) or even true? I asked my math teacher whether there is a theorem about this topic, and he couldn't remember one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nowhere monotonic continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42326/nowhere-monotonic-continuous-function) (googling for "continuous, nowhere monotone functions" gave me that as a result).

Comment: At the opposite extreme  there is a continuous surjection $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that (I): For any $m,n\in \Bbb N$  with $m\le 4^n$ there exists $p\in \Bbb N$ with $p\le 2^n$ such that $f$ maps $[(m-1)4^{-n},m4^{-n}]$ onto $[(p-1)2^{-n},p2^{-n}] $, and (II): For any $x\in [0,1]$ and any nbhd $U$ of $x,$ the set $\{y\in U: f(y)=f(x)\}$ is uncountable

Comment: Perhaps a simpler example. We can represent the Koch Snowflake as the the image $f([0,1])$ of a continuous$ f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R^2$ with $f(0)=f(1)$ with $f$ not constant on any interval of positive length.  Let $g(t)=x$ when $f(t)=(x,y). $ Then $g$ is continuous and nowhere monotonic. Extend $g$ to domain $\Bbb R$ by $g(t+n)=g(t)$ when $n\in \Bbb Z$ and $t\in [0,1].$... See Koch Snowflake in wikipedia.