# extending the intermediate value theorem with non-decreasing points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

After introducing the definition of "a function is non-decreasing at $x_{0}$ ":

> The function is said to be non-decreasing at $x_{0}$ if for all $x$-values in some interval about $x_{0}$ it is true that when $x_{0}<x$ then $y_{0} \leq y$, and when $x_{0}>x$ then $y_{0} \geq y$.

Can we extend the intermediate value theorem to the following?

> If $f$ is a continuous function on a closed interval $[a, b]$ with $f(a)<f(b)$, and if $y_{0}$ is any value strictly between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, that is $f(a)<y_{0}<f(b)$, then $y_{0}=f(c)$ for some $c$ in $(a, b)$ and **$\boldsymbol{f}$ is nondecreasing at the $c$**.

It was wrong according to the book[1], but I am unable to read it through due to some notations and concepts like residual subset and first-category subset, they are new to me, I am just familiar with concepts in textbooks like *Thomas Calculus* and *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis* by Richard Courant and Fritz John. Is there a way of minimum prerequisites to understand "Functions Whose Graphs “Cross No Lines”"?

[1]. Elementary Real Analysis: Second Edition, Brian S. Thomson, Judith B. Bruckner, Andrew M. Bruckner, Section 13.14.
The full book here http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf

Comment: You cannot ensure $f$ is nondecreasing. For a simple counterexample just take $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $f(x) = 1-x$. The function is strictly decreasing at every point in the open interval.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the tip, I just corrected the post.

Comment: Still false, but less elementarily so. There are functions  that are everywhere continuous and bounded, but nowhere monotone. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42326/742). Then just pick appropriate $a$ and $b$.